# Format of CSV string data for XGBoost model

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm brand new to Sagemaker and I'm having trouble finding examples of importing CSV-formatted String data into XGBoost.

Specifically, can it handle foreign characters (if yes, what encoding)?   How does it know which column (variable) I will need it to make a prediction on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use SageMaker XGBoost with csv input, you'll need to prepare your dataset in format `label, feature_1, feature_2, ...` in each row.

XGBoost can only handle numeric values as input data. If you have  foreign characters in the input data, you'll need to encoding it first before feeding it to XGBoost. Depending on your dataset, you should use the encoding method that make most sense to your data.

For csv input, SageMaker XGBoost always assume the first column to be the label/target.